# How do i access variable defined in map method outside render function

Tags: reactjs

I'm not getting how can i access variable defined in map() method outside render function in order to alert the variable value after clicking on the button and also even though i'm passing key in array, it is still throwing me `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method.`

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.handleEditClick = this.handleEditClick.bind(this);
     this.list = ''
}

handleEditClick() {
  alert(this.list);
}
render() {
   return(
     <div>
     {
       this.props.listArr.map((list,index) => {
         return(
           <div>
            <li key={index}>{list}
              <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
               <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>
              </div>
              <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
               <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onClick={this.handleEditClick} />
              </div>
            <hr/>
            </li>
           </div>
         )
      })
    }
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `key={index}` up to the `<div>`.

Comment: `handleEditClick(list) {...` and `onClick={() => this.handleEditClick(list)}`

Comment: Thanks @RickJolly, that worked, any reason why key didn't work on <li> ?

Comment: Must be on the root element since that is what React checks.